# Sending Android Notifications between app users

Tags: android

I am currently aiming to make an app in Android Studio that allows one user to push a button and another user to receive a push notification as a result. How might I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a server to act as an intermediary. Set up an API endpoint that your app can call to request a notification, and have your server dispatch a message to the receiving device using something like [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).